# Почему не работает встроенный JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, события

Почему не работает этот код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<img scr='applesred.jpg'
onmouseover="this.scr='applegreen.jpg'"
onmouseout="this.scr='applesred.jpg'">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: чайники часто такой ерундой занимаются

Comment: я по книге занимаюсь и все задания выполняю по порядку

Comment: попробуй ещё в тег кинуть
<script>Наш скрипт </script>

Comment: @Вика Пора менять книгу

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <img src='http://luxfon.com/large/201203/2608.jpg' onmouseover="this.src='http://luxfon.com/large/201203/2608.jpg'" 
   onmouseout="this.src='http://luxfon.com/large/201203/8886.jpg'" alt="img">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ответ верный, проверил дважды в этот раз, опечатка в первом была, у меня каким-то образом туда второй `src=""` попал. Обязательно вносите `alt=""`, правила есть правила. И с `this` тоже надо быть аккуратно, смотреть в контексте чего вы его используете.

Comment: Картинки добавил подгружаемые, чтоб результат виден был наглядно. Замените на свои.

Answer (score 5):

опечатка в свойстве
нужно src а не scr

Comment: точно,исправила а картинка не меняется...

Comment: а эти картинки есть в той же папке и с теми же названиями?

Comment: да,есть/Ладно видимо деййствительно нелучший  способ программирования